# Http status code is not working at the first attempt

Tags: powershell, status

I am new to `PowerShell`.I need your help to find the issue

I have to check prod and QA servers HTTP status code.

My script is failing and not displaying status code when I try for prod server but for QA it's working fine

If I run the script after I ran some random files in Powershell, that time my script is running fine and showing status codes like 200

but it's not at all running if I close all and run from the beginning. looks strange

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Can you post some code?  Questions: Are you trying to access the prod and QA servers over HTTPS?  If so, are CRL/OCSP checks enabled?  Are you using a proxy server?  Is that proxy server performing HTTPS inspection?  Might the proxy server(s) require Kerberos authentication?  Are any of the DNS names for prod, QA, or proxy hosts load-balanced between servers?  Are you making asynchronous web requests?

Comment: For check status use this code:
`$url = 'https://google.com'
$req = [system.Net.WebRequest]::Create($url)
try {$res = $req.GetResponse()} 
catch [System.Net.WebException] {$res = $_.Exception.Response}
$res.StatusCode #if need char status code
[int]$res.StatusCode #if need integer status code`

Comment: It was security protocol issue. Its working fine after i use protocol variables @vad I have used the same code and catch didn't throw any error.      Thank you for your answers..